# Dealing with memory making Swing animations

Tags: java, swing, animation, out-of-memory, heap-memory

It's my first time writting there but after reading and searching a lot about the subject I'm going to explain, I didn't found anything useful for me (I've checked a post of a guy explaining something similar about an iphone app, but without a final solution). Sorry for my english I'll try to do my best hehe :).

Ok, I'm starting: I have java application that shows a set of animations at the same time on a JPanel. These animations are java objects from **Animation** (inheritates from JLabel), a class of my own *that stores an array of ImageIcon* (representing the frames of animation) and an integer pointer, showing actual frame to paint (index).
That class has overriden the method setPaint() in that way:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(getImageAt(getCurrentIndex()).getImage(), getX2(), getY2(), getW(), getH(), null);
        //getImage at retrieves the frame at a "index" position from frame array.
        if (getCurrentIndex() < getTotal() - 1) {
            incrementIndex();//increments frame by 1 (next frame)
        } else {
            resetIndex();//set index to 0 (frame 0)
        }
}
```

On the other hand, we have **Display**, which inheritates from JPanel and is responsible for repainting the panel (it uses I javax.swing.Timer object and **repaints every 50 ms**).

All the images from every Animation object have the same size 768x576 and png format with transparencies (thus I can paint many animations at a time).

The problem is that when I load an animation it occupies too much memory because it creates I don't know why either how 200 MB of "int" objects apart of the 2MB that really occupies. When I load more animations the heap's space of the JVM rockets (up to **1.7 GB**... I didn't want to try anymore xD). For example, **6 animations may be 405 frames** (90 in average).
I've collected this data with JProfiler, but I can't post the capture so this what I get:
  Memory usage of my app by JProfiler:

- java.awtRectangle 3351 KB
- sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D 16.510 KB (I think this is the size of all the animations and sounds logical).
- java.lang.String 669KB
- int[] 1337 MB
  ...

---

In display, the loading images process is in this way:

```
add(new Animation (loadImageSet(Constants.DIR_CINTA_EJE,"all"),
            Constants.A_CINTA_EJE, 75,-200,768,576));//1
```

Where DIR_CINTA_EJE is the directory where all the frames of that animation are and the value "all" means that I want to load all the frames.

There is a way to avoid that memory used grows linearly with the number of animations? Why those ​​"int" values occupies so much? Are they the pixels of each image?

And yes, I have Increased my heap space up to 2GB and it's working, but at a high cost.
Thank you very much for all the help you can provide. I love this forum, really.

Regards.

Comment: the int[] which is the real concern, is the Raster data (the image bitmap data). The other memory you list is insignificant.

Comment: So the only solution is to recreate the animations to a lower resolution? For now, I'll try that, thanksss!

Comment: Can you post `getImage()` code?

Comment: Get image only access a position from an array. There is the code:

Comment: public ImageIcon getImageAt(int index){
        return _images[index];
    }//Class Animation

Comment: I've spent all the afternoon reducing quality of images and I have deleted 1/3 of them for each animation. Now 8 animations occupies 1.3 GB of memory and I have 50 in average per animation.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy it is not possible to store Raster in another way?? I mean, other way to allocate images in memory, because its a bit crappy losing quality and number of frames in animations :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working hard looking for a satisfactory solution and finally I've got it!
That's what I have done:

Class Animation does no more inheritates from JLabel it only implements ActionListener, in which `actionPerformed()` method I increment the frame to show for each one (I use Timer class). Therefore, Animation does no more override `paintComponent()` method (it's work for DisplayPanel).

In DisplayPanel, I use thre global variables:

```
private BufferedImage _auxiliary_image;
private ImageIcon _image2display;
private ArrayList<Animation>;//I store there all the running animations there
```

And now, I override there the DisplayPanel `paintComponent()`, thus:

```
 @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < _animations.size(); i++) {
            if(i==0){
                _auxiliary_image.createGraphics().drawImage(_animations.get(i).getActual().getImage(), 0, 0, Color.white, null);
            }else{
                _auxiliary_image.createGraphics().drawImage(_animations.get(i).getActual().getImage(), 0, 0, null);
            }

        }
        _image2display.setImage(_auxiliary_image);
        _image2display.paintIcon(this, g, 50, -200);
    }
```

The reason why I difference two cases, one for i==0 and another for the rest of frames is that on painting I saw a black background and the whole positions of the animation, so is this way that I solve the issue.

Now, with 8 animations with 50 frames each one occuppies only 360 MB of memory instead 1.3 GB I get last time =) (I only paint one image, which results from merging all the frames to be printed at the same time for each animation).

Thank you and I hope this could help!!!